# Installing Packages For Standalone Version of Spyder version 5

Tags: package, spyder

I have downloaded Spyder version 5 (standalone) for python programming.

I do not have Anaconda and do not wish to download it.

My question is how do i download packages when using the standalone version of Spyder?

Thank you.

Comment: You can't install packages in the same environment where Spyder lives. This is to not mess with dependencies. You need to set up a separate environment, like you do for other IDE's as well, and connect this to Spyder via spyder-kernels. See https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#using-existing-environment